# Why would the same drive give "Error loading OS" in SATA mode, but not in IDE?

Tags: windows, boot, virtualbox, sata, ide

I'm using **VirtualBox**, and I have a VMDK file that references `\\.\PhysicalDrive2` as `fullDevice`.

The virtual machine is in BIOS mode, set as Windows 10 x64.

If I attach this VMDK file to a SATA controller, it fails with `Error loading operating system`.
If I attach this VMDK file to an IDE controller, it boots fine off the flash drive.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out while I was writing this question.

I already had other devices attached, and for whatever reason, VirtualBox only seems to support booting off the *first* SATA storage device. This seems like a potential bug.

When I switch it into the first position, it boots fine in SATA mode.